# How to get whitespace to append mid tab complete

Tags: bash, bash-completion

So as an example of a program that does this properly.

If you type:

```
git stash list
```

in a terminal

then move your cursor over to the "h"
and press TAB your output will be:

```
git stash h list
```

and your cursor would be on the last "h"

I thought that adding the -S (suffix) command to my compgen would append a space, but alas, it does not.

```
COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$1"  -S " " -- ${cur}))
```

And as an example, my program would instead output:

```
git stashh list.
```

How do I get the desired behavior? Is my suffix approach correct? Do I need to get bash to ignore the fact that it is a white space?

Should I add -o nospace so that I always get the exact amount of spaces I expect? Adding -o nospace anywhere in my COMPREPLY doesn't seem eliminate the spaces? Maybe I'm not using correct?

command with -o nospace for the record is:

```
COMPREPLY=($(compgen -o nospace -W "$1"  -S " " -- ${cur}))
```

Comment: please show your full compspec